# In Rails' form_for view builder, can the value of two input fields (integers) multiplied be displayed in a subsequent line in the form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-for

I have a form_for view builder for a model (purchase):

```
<%= form_for(@purchase) do |f| %>

        <%= f.collection_select :product_id, Product.all, :id, :name, placeholder: 'Product Name' %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :date, placeholder: 'date' %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :quantity, placeholder: 'quantity' %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :vendor, placeholder: 'vendor' %><br>
        <br><%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

Products have a price (float) and there's an integer input field for quantity. Can I multiply and display product.price and purchase.quantity in this form using something like

```
<% if @purchase.product %>
        <%= @purchase.calculate_total %>
<% end %>
```

Where calculate_total =

```
def calculate_total
     quantity * product.price            
end
```

Comment: `.html.erb` files are static, so if you want to show some information based on things that will change in your screen, you need to use javascript for asynchronous rendering

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.